# Background image not stretching to full height of container in Firefox/IE/Edge

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, height, microsoft-edge

I'm having trouble with the fact that Firefox/IE/Edge browsers don't read percentage height the same way Chrome does.

I want my figure element to stretch to the full height of its container, whenever more content is added to the Div element which is alongside the figure element.

Here is the HTML:

```
<article class="TextAndImage">
   <a href="someLink">
      <figure class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 pull-left noPaddingLeft" style="background-image: url("image1.jpg");"><img width="960" class="img-responsive " src="blabla"></figure>
   </a>
   <div class="pullRight textDiv">
     <p>&nbsp;</p>
     <p>&nbsp;</p>
     <h2>SomeHeading</h2>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. pharetra</p>
     <p class="pButton">
         <a class="btn btn-default" href="someLink" value="">Click Me</a>
     </p>
    </div>
</article>
```

The CSS:

```
article.TextAndImage {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;    
}

figure {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
}

div.textDiv [
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
}
```

In Chrome, the image always stretches to full height when there is more text in the textDiv element. In the other browsers they ignore the percentage height property and the image doesn't stretch. Searching for other solutions in Stack Overflow, there was an option to set the body and html height to 100% but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Any help/solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I try to make a test with your code with Edge and Chrome.

I got the similar results in both browser.

Below is my testing result using Chrome.

[image]

Below is my testing result using Edge.

[image]

Can you show us your output in different browsers. So that we can see the issue there on your side.

Then we can again try to provide you a suggestion to solve the issue.

Regards

Deepak